# how do i reduce the tool tip text pop up Delay?

Tags: java

Is it possible to make a ToolTipText pop up instantly on hover instead of having to wait the 2-3 sec delay?`

```
button1.setToolTipText("hi")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`ToolTipManager#setInitialDelay(long milliseconds)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html#setInitialDelay%28int%29)

Just understand that this will effect all the tooltips in your application and AFAIK, there is no way to effect a single tooltip without implementing the entire base API yourself

Comment: Out it at the start of your application, typically after you've initialised the look and feel and probably before you initialise the main frame